# Intent filter using path,pathPrefix, or pathPattern

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, intentfilter

My test uri string is

http://test.host.com/path/test.html?key1=val1&key2=val2

And I make intent-filter in manifest

A. scheme & host (It works but I do not want)

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data
        android:scheme="http"
        android:host="test.host.com"
    />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

B. A & path(pathPrefix, pathPattern) (Not worked)

```
    <data
        android:scheme="http"
        android:host="test.host.com"

        1. android:path="path/test.html" -> not worked (link to chrome broswer)
        2. android:path="path"           -> not worked (link to chrome broswer)
        3. android:pathPrefix="path"     -> not worked (link to chrome broswer)
        4. android:pathPattern="user/invite.*"  -> same (I do not know pattern)

    />
```

I want to start my app when **only** (path/test.html),

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are missing the slash at the beginning. The following should work:

```
android:path="/path/test.html"
```

OR

```
android:pathPrefix="/path/test.html"
```

Comment: android:pathPrefix="/path/test.html"==> It works too.

Answer (score 13):

If you need start your app **only If** for link `/path/test.html` Then Use `android:path` attribute in `data` tag only

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
        android:host="test.host.com"
        android:path="/path/test.html" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

As `android:path` attribute specifies a complete path that is matched against the complete path in an Intent object.
**But** `android:pathPrefix` attribute  specifies a partial path that is matched against only the initial part of the path in the Intent object.

So when use `android:pathPrefix` attribute not `android:path` attribute That mean your app may start for `/path/test.html`, `/path/test.html?key1=value1`,`/path/test.html?key1=value1&key2=value2`,etc

More Information about [android doc for data tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) into `intent-filter`

Answer (score 5):

The `pathPrefix` attribute specifies a partial path that is matched against only the **initial part of the path** in the Intent object.

`android:pathPrefix="/path/"` will also work.